# Blazor: Custom AuthenticationStateProvider never returns authorised state

Tags: authentication, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I've got a very basic blazor project setup to test authorisation via custom authentication mechanism by implementing AuthenticationStateProvider.

I've faked the authorisation state to always return a faked logged in user and added `@attribute [Authorized]` to my routable page component but it always shows a "Not Authorised" message when navigated to.

Started by adding the necessary initialisation in Startup.cs

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

I've implemented a custom AuthenticationStateProvider that always returns a logged in user:

```
public class LocalStorageAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@fake.com","apiauth_type_email")
            });
    
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
 }
```

..and I've registered my custom provider:

```
    services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, LocalStorageAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

..and I've added AuthorizeRouteView to App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Finally, I've added the authorised attribute to my routable page:

```
@page "/personal/dashboard"
@attribute [Authorize]
```

but when I navigate there, I'm always met with "Not authorised" message. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@fake.com","apiauth_type_email")
});
```

You have typos and are not providing an `authenticationType` for `ClaimsIdentity`.  Your code should look like:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
  {
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@fake.com")
  }, "apiauth_type_email");
```